# Add Member to Directory Role in Microsoft Graph API - Insufficient Privileges

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

The [docs state](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/directoryrole_post_members):

> One of the following scopes is required to execute this API: Directory.ReadWrite.All OR Directory.AccessAsUser.All

http://jwt.calebb.net/ confirms that **Directory.ReadWrite.All** is one of the roles for my token, however the following request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/{directoryRoleObjectId}/members/$ref
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{userObjectId}"
}
```

Returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "{id}",
      "date": "2016-11-25T15:18:07"
    }
  }
}
```

Running a GET on the directoryRole returns data, so the Read permissions seem to be working. What am I missing?

Comment: This should work (with those permissions).  Checked Directory.AccessAsUser.All (using an Admin account) and this works (checked using Graph Explorer.  Will need to check separately for application permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directory.AccessAsUser.All (using an Admin account) allows you to add/remove users from a directory role.  NOTE: this is a delegated permission. As far as I can tell, no other permissions allows this operation, and we'll need to fix our docs.  I will need to check back with some of our development team on this.
Question for you: Is there a reason why you need to use Application Permissions, and can't use Delegated Permissions?

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the info - we should be able to implement the delegated permissions as an alternative, and in fact it probably makes more sense to do it that way too.

Comment: OK - that's good to hear.  Please let us know if this option won't work for you.  And thanks again for reporting the error in the docs.

Comment: Yes thanks - we got it working using delegated permissions and it turned out that this is more appropriate than app permissions for our scenario. On a slightly related topic, would you know if it is possible to add members to Exchange rolegroups via MS Graph? The equivalent of the Add-RoleGroupMember cmdlet in PowerShell.